# java multithreading synchronization confirmation?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

1) if synchronized(this) is used, which means that any of the two threads will lock on factor instance and increment val variable value till the loop exits. 
    so synchronized(this) means here that we should not use any other instance variables. We have to use only the variables of factor instance inside the synchronized block?

2) if synchronized(addition) means here that we have to use only  add variable not the val variable of factor instance class?

There is a big confusion regarding this synchronization block . 
what i understood  is synchronization block will lock on the object's instance and guard the operation and make it thread safe. But using different instance really means that it should guard only that particular instance variables not any other instance variables. Can anyone explain in depth concept regarding this relating with the code provided below

```
class Factor implements Runnable
{
 int val = 0;
Addition addtion = new Addition();

@Override
public void run()
{

    currInsLock();
    diffInsLock();
}

// locking on the current instance which is this
// we will use synchronized(this)

public void currInsLock() 
{
    synchronized (this) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
                try
                  {
                     Thread.sleep(100);
                  }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }   
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"---val value lock on this obj -->"+val++);

        }
    }
}



// locking on the different instance
public void diffInsLock() 
{
    synchronized (addtion) 
    {

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
                try
                  {
                     Thread.sleep(100);
                  }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }   
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"---val value lock on addition obj -->"+val++);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"---add value lock on addition obj -->"+addtion.add++);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Addition class :

```
public class Addition  
{
   public int add=0;
}
```

The Main class

```
 public class ConcurrentDoubt {

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Factor factor=new Factor();

  Thread thread1=new Thread(factor);
  Thread thread2=new Thread(factor);

   thread1.start();
   thread2.start();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you use as object's monitor is not really important, it could be any object, I would even say that ideally we should never use `this` as object's monitor but rather a `private final Object` instance to better protect our class because if outside your code, we use the instance of your class as object's monitor it could prevent your class to work properly.

The key point is to use exact same object's monitor anytime you want to modify or access to anything that you want to protect (member variables, class instances...) if what you want to protect is accessed/modified outside a `synchronized` block or with a different object's monitor, your code is no more thread-safe because you don't prevent concurrent accesses or modifications anymore. Indeed only one thread can execute code protected by a `synchronized` block for a given object's monitor, so it you have 2 different object's monitors to protect the same thing, you could have 2 threads accessing/modifying what you try to protect.

So here, you use `this` and `addtion` as object's monitors to protect your member variable `val` so your code is not thread-safe, you need to use the same object's monitor.

Assuming that you want to use `this` as object's monitor to protect your member variable `val`, your code should rather be:

```
synchronized (addtion) {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        ...
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println(
                Thread.currentThread().getName() + 
                "---val value lock on addition obj -->" + val++
            );
        }
        System.out.println(
            Thread.currentThread().getName() + 
            "---add value lock on addition obj -->" + addtion.add++
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: OP: "...using different instance really means that it should guard only that particular instance variables not any other instance variables..." -- I guess you need to emphasize there's mutual exclusion of threads, so all access inside the block to data is sequenced per-thread.

Comment: @VictorSorokin thx for the feedback, but frankly speaking I still don't clearly understand this sentence of the OP. But what you propose is somehow what I mean by `your code is no more thread safe because you don't prevent concurrent accesses or modifications anymore`

Comment: @VictorSorokin I modified a little bit my answer to add your remark, thx

Comment: I saw it like OP not realizing access to _all_ instance vars is sequenced for code inside particular sync block, not just to the one used as monitor (actually, to _all_ data accessed inside a block, not just instance variables). But I may be wrong  :)